# The NSTimer that doesn't invalidate (or a weird memory problem I can't solve)

Tags: objective-c, ios, ios4

I'm having a huge problem with the NSTimer object. I can't explain myself this behavior, and I will try to explain as best as I can.

I have a function in my view which is called placeAdvertisement. In this function there are multiple operations with static methods that uses as parameter one of my objects (another view):

```
if (self.adsController == nil) {
    self.adsController = [[AdsController alloc] ...];
    [self.view addSubView: self.adsController.view;
}

if (banner != nil) {

    self.adsController.banner = banner;
    [self.adsController updateBanner];

    //If a previous timer is still working (because this method can be called multiple times) invalidate
    if (self.adsTimer != nil)
        [self.adsTimer invalidate];

    [Advertisement operation1: self.adsController];
    [Advertisement operation2: self.adsController];

    self.adsTimer = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval: 5 ...];

}
```

The last timer calls to another function, called quitAdvertisement, but he never gets called (when the failure is produced). The code seems to work well in normal conditions, the advertisement controller works correctly, the banner is placed and the timer calls adsTimer, which quits the banner.

The problem appears if a pop the view (returning back) and the push another one again. Once the view is loaded I push a button that fires the code placed before. The code executes well, **but in "the middle" of the execution**, in [Advertisement operation1: self.adsController] appears EXC_BAD_ACCESS:

[MyController AdvertisementController]: message sent to deallocated instance 0x4e9b420

**It's like in the middle of the code, my object gets deallocated**. I don't have any code that calls release of the object, just the dealloc, which has not been called for this instance of the view (Has been called for the previous view, which was popped up).

How can be this possible? Is there any way to debug that in better conditions?

I've used NSZombieEnabled.

Thanks!

### ***Little edit for the comments***

1. AdsController is allocated like:

   self.adsController = [[AdsController alloc] initWithNibName:nil bundle:nil];

After in dealloc method:

```
[self.adsController release];

[super dealloc];
```

2. Respect to the timer:

   It is allocated with repeat NO. After in dealloc:

   if (self.adsTimer != nil) [self.adsTimer invalidate];

Is this correct?

Comment: How do you create `MyController`? Do you autorelease it?

Comment: If the timer executes only once, e.g repeats:NO, you need to set self.adsTimer = nil in the method the timer called, because the timer will be deallocated after. If you did not nullify it, if (self.adsTimer != nil) will try to access a dangling pointer.

Comment: Thanks Saphrosit and Davyd. I'm very grateful. Please check the edit to the original post ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just to clarify what was the problem.

There was one NSNotification that was beign pushed only if the timer was active. This led me to believe that the problem was in the timer, but was the notification beign captured by a form that was released.

So, it's important to be very carefully removing the observer from any notification when a form is poped out.

I just want to thank your help.

Answer (score 1):

From the code posted it looks as if when you 'pop' this view, there may still be an NSTimer valid that will be retaining its target.  You could try invalidating the NSTimer `[[self adsTimer] invalidate]` in your `viewWillDisappear:` method (assuming you have a viewController - **and** if you don't, I'd recommend using one).

Tricky to diagnose from the code you have provided - while brevity is great, in this case a bit more might be helpful.

Comment: Thank you so much Matthew. viewWillDisappear will be perfect for the purpose. The problem is that the view that is holding the code shown before has been placed with addSubView to another view. So, viewWillDisappear is not called. Is there any way to detect that the view is disappearing without that event?

Comment: In your UIView subclass, you could override removeFromSuperView and put relevant code in there. You'll need to call [super removeSuperView] there as well. Hope this is of help (I'm a bit unclear as to your overall design / interaction of your views).

Comment: Thanks Matthew for your help. I'm sorry because maybe is hardest to explain than I've imagined.

I have not been able to override removeFromSuperView, but I have detected the event launching a notification and adding an observer. Maybe I'm doing something so bad, because know the EXC_BAD_ACCESS has been thrown setting a property now, wich seems so weird to me.

Always happens if I manage the UI as fast as I can.

I can't understand, If I'm allocating a timer and invalidating in the dealloc, how is it possible that this is happening in other view wich is "alive"?

Answer (score 1):

`[NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval]` will add the timer to the current run loop. If the current thread is a background thread, it's possible that the thread has ended and the timer will never get fired. Try to add the timer to the main run loop.